# Sendmail greatly increases value of Total DISK WRITE

Tags: linux, sendmail, io

Sendmail is installed on the server.

It sends an average of *6 emails at 3K per second* and writes *18 files* in `/var/spool/mqueue-client`.

Because of this high disk writes iotop: `Total DISK WRITE: 1605.77 K/s`. On another test server I wrote a script that sends `20 emails at 3K` and `DISK WRITE` increases from 0 to 1500 K/s

Who can tell why such a high Total DISK WRITE depends sendmail and how can I reduce it?

Comment: Are you sending 6 mails (with size of 3K) per second or are you sending 6 mails at a 3K per second rate?

Answer (score 0):

If your */var/spool/mqueue* and your */var/spool/mqueue-client* directories have *qf*, *df* and *xf* subdirectories, then you can mount the *xf* ones in memory. If such subdirectories do not exist, wait for your queue to empty, then stop sendmail, create them and mount as appropriately.